# How can i use slenium in Python to click the button?

Tags: python, selenium, button

I try to find how can I click on button for accept cookies with a python in selenium,

I used a lot of convinations but nothing works  :(

This is the element:

```
<button class="button primary cookie-button" ng-click="$ctrl.allowAllCookies()">
                        <span class="ng-binding">Todas las cookies</span>
                    </button>
```

I used in other with:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
time.sleep(2)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "onetrust-banner-sdk")))
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]')))
element.click()
```

This is all the code from button:

```
<div class="text-center cookie-controls"> <button class="button primary cookie-button" ng-click="$ctrl.allowCookiesSelection()"> <span class="ng-binding">Permitir selección</span> </button> <button class="button primary cookie-button" ng-click="$ctrl.allowAllCookies()"> <span class="ng-binding">Todas las cookies</span>
```

But now I don't have id to use and I don't know how can I use.

Comment: can you share a link to that page?

Answer (score 1):

Another way is as follows:

```
buttons = driver.find_element(By.TAGNAME, 'button')

for button in buttons:
    if button.text() == 'Accept Cookies'
        cookies_Button = button
        cookies_Button.click()
```

The code above should return all buttons and the `for` statement will loop through them looking for any buttons which read Accept Cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to XML you presenting in the question you can locate this button with several XPath locators.
For example try this:

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(@ng-click,"allowAllCookies")]'))).click()
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast response, now no have any error but nothing happends (not click on web).
This is all code from buttons for cookie:
```
<div class="text-center cookie-controls">
                    <button class="button primary cookie-button" ng-click="$ctrl.allowCookiesSelection()">
                        <span class="ng-binding">Permitir selección</span>
                    </button>
                    <button class="button primary cookie-button" ng-click="$ctrl.allowAllCookies()">
                        <span class="ng-binding">Todas las cookies</span>
```

Comment: Please put your code inside the question to make it readable

Comment: I added the code from button in the question..

Comment: Not a XML of web elements, your selenium code. where is it?